# ¿Cómo crear una nueva columna usando un group_by en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(Id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5), 
               valor=c("A","A","A","A","B","A","A","A","B","A","A","A"))
df
   Id valor
1   1     A
2   1     A
3   1     A
4   2     A
5   2     B
6   3     A
7   4     A
8   4     A
9   4     B
10  4     A
11  5     A
12  5     A
```

Lo que deseo es crear una columna en donde se asigne por `id`, el valor de la `A` si en la columna `valor` todos son `A`, si hay una `B`, entonces lo que le correspondería a todas las filas del `id` sería `B`.

El resultado esperado es el que se muestra a continuación.

```
df
   Id valor final
1   1     A     A
2   1     A     A
3   1     A     A
4   2     A     B
5   2     B     B
6   3     A     A
7   4     A     B
8   4     A     B
9   4     B     B
10  4     A     B
11  5     A     A
12  5     A     A
```

Una idea que tengo es convertirlo de long a wide y de ahí trabajar por columnas. Sé que saldría, pero quisiera una solución sin tener la necesidad de transformar los datos. Se puede hacer un `group_by()` por id y aplicar un `mutate()`?

Cómo se podría solucionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo como esto:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% 
              filter(valor == "B") %>%
              group_by(Id) %>% 
              summarise(final = unique(valor)),
            by = "Id") %>% 
  mutate(final = ifelse(is.na(final), valor, final))
```

Comentarios:

- Hacemos una primer consulta, donde nos quedamos con los `Id` dónde hay valores `B`
- Con un `left_join()` relacionamos cada tabla
- Fila por fila, simplemente verificamos si el `Id` es uno de los que tiene `B` y completamos `final` con dicho valor, sino con el de la propia fila.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Patricio.